# Defining ArrayList gives error

Tags: java, arraylist

I've been working on a program in which augmetnts can be installed. Within the ship class I have this down:

```
public ArrayList<Augment> installedAugments = new ArrayList<Augment>(){
    ArrayList IA = new ArrayList <Augment>();
    for (Augment a:theGame.augments){
        if (a.installed){
            IA.add(a);
        }
    }
    return IA;
}
```

(the Game.augments is public)

The error as Eclipse detects it is after delcaring IA they want a {, which does not make sense as I have a nearly identical function which runs perfectly well.

Answer (score 0):

If this code is supposed to be a method called `installedAugments`, it should be :

```
public ArrayList<Augment> installedAugments () {
    ArrayList IA = new ArrayList <Augment>();
    for (Augment a:theGame.augments){
        if (a.installed){
            IA.add(a);
        }
    }
    return IA;
}
```

(This is assuming `theGame` is an instance variable or static variable of this class. If that's not the case, it should be a parameter of the method)

If it is supposed to be a declaration + initialization of a class member called `installedAugments`, it should be :

```
public ArrayList<Augment> installedAugments = new ArrayList<Augment>();
```

(though in that case I'd make it private)

It can't be both.

Answer (score 0):

This function signature is totally wrong

```
public ArrayList<Augment> installedAugments = new ArrayList<Augment>(){
```

Why?

your function signature does not follow the rule which is as follows :

```
modifier returnType nameOfMethod (Parameter List) {
 // method body
}
```

when you follow the right structure

```
public ArrayList<Augment> installedAugments () {

    .....
    Rest of your code
    ...
    return IA;
}
```